# What is the song that plays in Naruto Shippuden when Deidara fights Gaara?

Tags: naruto, music

I've been searching for that song for a *really* long time but I can't find it. It's kinda sad (?? for me at least) and it has a violin or cello or something like that.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. Could you also provide the episode number and the timestamp?

Comment: Do you refer to 5:05,9:27 or 12:27 of the fight? Gaara vs Deidara link :  http://bit.ly/2BT6knM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the track is actually called "Stalemate"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HN5sj6Wpas4

Answer (score 1):

It's called Deidara's theme. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Kd4mOSrTh8

At 0:42, the strings start playing.